# How to preg_split a string?

Tags: php

I wish a number to display like a tel number, using preg_split:

```
$number = '1234567890';
// preg_split
$number = '123 456 7890';
```

e.g. maybe:

```
implode(' ', preg_split('/pattern/', $number))
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: What are the conditions of splitting it? just the package-length? Just insert Whitespaces at the correct position. No need for regex imho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$number = '1234567890';
$number = preg_replace('/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/','$1 $2 $3',$number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this-

```
$str = "1234567890";
$split = str_split($str, 3);
echo $split[0]." ".$split[1]." ".$split[2].$split[3];
```

OR

```
     $number= "1234567890";
    echo substr($number,0,3)." ".substr($number,3,3)." ".substr($number,5);
```